# FB Messenger get email address from fbid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I can get the Senders first and last name, etc using `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/fbid?access_token=PAGEACCESS_TOKEN`. How do I secure access to other information available described in the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) that is more than what is defined on the [messenger docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile)

Comment: You don’t. Facebook has made the user ids in messenger page-scoped for a reason; you are not supposed to get more information about them making random API calls. Plus, accessing someone’s e-mail requires their permission first of all.

Comment: Can I request permission from within Messenger itself?

Comment: No. At most you can perhaps use account linking, to have them create an “account” in your app, and then link that to the messenger user.

Comment: Roger. Thank you.